# npm-css import not entire file of bootstrap.css

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have Ionic app and trying to use Datepicker from Angular UI Bootstrap. It doesn't have own style files and uses bootstrap.css. So I installed bootstrap and try to import style file with npm-css in my index.css file:

`@import "bootstrap";`

then I use

`npm-css index.css -o bundle.css`

Issue is that bundle.css file contain not entire bootstrap.css file.
Only errors in console are about bootstrap glyphicons and I think this is not related with my problem.

Before this I used npm-css without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is issue with `npm-css` and I can't catch it. But when I switch to `rework-npm` all entire file is imported and all working fine.